# How to tag the question "Cannot post on Japanese message board because I'm using Tor"?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I tried to retag the question [Cannot post on Japanese message board because I'm using Tor](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/1655/88) today. However it felt quite hard to select a good one. What would you say what the best tags for this questions are?

Comment: Good question; we should have some sort of tag for questions about blocked websites / services in general (since I'm sure we'll continue to get these). Not sure what though.

Comment: I'd suggest something like `blocked-services` - this is going to become an increasingly common question.